# Where did Martin Hellman acknowledge Ralph Merkle's contribution to public-key cryptography?

Tags: diffie-hellman, reference-request

I am trying to find the article to reference when discussing the Diffie-Hellman key exchange.

According to Wikipedia Hellman said that

> The system...has since become known as Diffie–Hellman key exchange. While that system was first described in a paper by Diffie and me, it is a public key distribution system, a concept developed by Merkle, and hence should be called 'Diffie–Hellman–Merkle key exchange' if names are to be associated with it. I hope this small pulpit might help in that endeavor to recognize Merkle's equal contribution to the invention of public key cryptography.

Any ideas where I can find the original article? The wikipedia link itself is dead.

Comment: You can find it on Ralph Merkles [website](http://www.merkle.com).

Comment: Do you have direct link, I cannot find the article.

Comment: [Here](http://www.merkle.com/1974/PuzzlesAsPublished.pdf) is the paper and [here](http://www.merkle.com/1974/) the story.

Comment: I am trying to find Hellman's acknowledgement itself, not the paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The oral interview can be found at:
http://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/11299/107353/1/oh375mh.pdf

Comment: Ha of course.  I found it there also, but wasn't sure if that was exactly what you were looking for so I left you the more general link in case it wasn't.

Answer (score 6):

The source of that quote is:

Hellman, M. E. (2002). An overview of public key cryptography. *IEEE Communications Magazine*, *40*(5), 42-49.

That paper is currently available here:

https://netlab.ulusofona.pt/im/teoricas/OverviewPublicKeyCryptography.pdf

Here's the complete quote:

> The system I called the ax1x2 system in this paper has since become
> known as Diffie-Hellman key exchange. While that system was first
> described in a paper by Diffie and me, it is a public key distribution
> system, a concept developed by Merkle, and hence should be called
> "Diffie-Hellman-Merkle key exchange" if names are to be associated
> with it. I hope this small pulpit might help in that endeavor to
> recognize Merkle's equal contribution to the invention of public key
> cryptography. Space does not permit an explanation of the quirk of
> fate that seems to have deprived Merkle of the credit he deserves, but
> a quirk it is.